# Notation for the set of edges of a directed graph whose tails belong to vertex set $S_1$ and heads belong to $S_2$

Tags: graph-theory, notation, directed-graphs

For a directed graph $D$, and sets of vertices $S_1$, $S_2$, is there a standard notation to refer to the set of directed edges whose tail belong to $S_1$ and head belong to $S_2$? If so what text specifically uses this notation?

I have been told that a notation is defined in Bollobas's *Modern Graph Theory*, but have not been able to get my hands on it yet.

Comment: Could you please give an example of such definition? I mean the diagram of a directted graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bollobas uses the notation $\vec{E}(S_1,S_2)$.